# 「実父」's pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I have always pronounced the word [実父]{じっぷ}, and it seems the dictionaries agree. ([jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%AE%9F%E7%88%B6). Also WWWJDIC, I would put a link here, but it seems the link I get on WWWJDIC is dynamic and the content can't be reproduced with a link.)

However, I just heard this word said in an anime as [実父]{じつふ}. I have not heard this pronunciation before. How common is it? I found [this page](https://furigana.info/w/%E5%AE%9F%E7%88%B6) with a list of pronunciation variants including じっぷ、ちち、おやじ、じつぷ with their textual usage percentages, but じつふ　is not among them. (The semantic nuances are not within the scope of this question.)

[This 知恵袋 thread](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1068767985) seems to confirm [実父]{じつふ} as a possible pronunciation. But is it regional?

Comment: There is a stable link to the entry https://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&q=1321420, but as far as I know jisho.org is based on WWWJDIC, so it's just the same piece of information. (The link to the entry in jisho.org would be https://jisho.org/word/%E5%AE%9F%E7%88%B6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「じっぷ」 is the only "dictionary" pronunciation of 「実父」, period, but that does not mean "everyone" actually pronounces the word that way.  I do hear 「じつふ」 as well, but I highly doubt it is regional.

In non-technical and non-formal, day-to-day kind of speech, however, far more native speakers use 「実{じつ}の父{ちち}」 than 「じっぷ」 or 「じつふ」 (or even than those two combined if I were to be completely honest).  「実父」 is way more often used in **written** Japanese, which is possibly why one might not be as keen on its pronunciation as Japanese-learners might expect.

This is why your first sentence "I have always pronounced the word 実父{じっぷ}." took me by surprise.  It made me think you were a lawyer or something because as a native speaker, I know I use 「実の父」 virtually 100% of the time in oral communication.

Finally, 「実父」 is not the only word that many people pronounce differently from what the dictionary says.  Some 'famous' examples would be:

- 「早急」 (urgent)：「さっきゅう (dic.)」 vs. 「そうきゅう」
- 「乳離れ」 (weaning)：「ちばなれ (dic.)」 vs. 「ちちばなれ」
- 「続柄」 (relationship)：「つづきがら (dic.)」 vs. 「ぞくがら」

The list goes on and on.